# Pandas read_sql with sqlite is very slows on simple queries is this expected?

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

I've created 24 large sqlite databases to help handle a large volume of data which is too big to manage directly in a pandas dataframe due to memory constraints. Each database is around 4m rows, 229 columns with a range of string,integer and float data points. They are c2.2Gb when saved to the hard drive.

Having now tried to use the new databases, I'm finding queries very slow. This query to simply count the rows in the data takes 50 seconds to run:

`df = pd.read_sql('SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM MY_TABLE', engine)`

The engine is created with sqlalchemy,

`engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('sqlite:///my_path/my_db.db')`

I've also tried `sqlite3.connection()` with similar results.

While running the process barely uses 6% to 7% of CPU at peak and there is no increase in RAM.

Is this performance to be expected, or is there likely to be an issue with the databases I've created? Is there anything else I can consider to speed up this processing?

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Probably check how long it takes to run the same code without interfacing with pandas. Then you can dig further to see if connection issues have anything to do with it.

Comment: As an aside, `df = pd.read_sql('SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM MY_TABLE', engine)` looks gross. I wouldn't be using `pandas` as a proxy to execute SQL unless I _really_ needed to. In relation to the question, I think that's high. There are postgres reasons for why counting rows are slow; I'm trying to see if they translate to SQLite

Comment: I can't seem to find any tricks for SQLite :/ Is there an index on ID?

Comment: Thanks all, adding an index to the ID field improved things considerably for the `COUNT` statement (c50 seconds down to 3) but other simple queries like a `GROUP BY` even using just indexed columns still takes c150 seconds. I've also ran the same queries without interfacing with pandas but I wasn't able to detect any difference in performance and processor usage is still negligible